# Testing Linux kernel image in Qemu

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, qemu

i'm new to embedded linux field. i am trying to emulate arm develpmnt board using Qemu and boot linux on to it. i compiled the kernel and got the uImage.but when i test this image on qemu it shows--
    `qemu: fatal: Trying to execute code outside RAM or ROM at 0x50008000
     R00=00000000 R01=00000183 R02=00000100 R03=00000000
     R04=00000000 R05=00000000 R06=00000000 R07=00000000
     R08=00000000 R09=00000000 R10=00000000 R11=00000000
     R12=00000000 R13=00000000 R14=00000000 R15=50008000
     PSR=400001d3 -Z-- A svc32
     Aborted.`

i used this command for testing
     `qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -kernel /root/ls6410/kernel/s3c-linux-2.6.28.6-Real6410/arch/arm/boot/uImage.`

can anyone suggest an method to fix this?

thanks,

Comment: Did you use the versatile_defconfig while compiling the kernel?

Comment: i didnt use versatile_defconfig when i compiled the kernel. but when i used that command, it shows error in making the image 'drivers/char/led.c:27:28: error: plat/regs-gpio.h: No such file or directory....    make[2]: *** [drivers/char/led.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [drivers/char] Error 2
make: *** [drivers] Error 2'

Comment: you're probably using the kernel of a particular vendor(for a particular development board).Use the vanilla kernel from kernel.org

Comment: i tried using vanilla kernel. The previous error of 'qemu fatal' didn't happen but when i load  the new image, the qemu shows only a blank screen and nothing is hapenning..